# Find strings consisting of one or more words joined by an underscore

Tags: shell, terminal, macos-mojave

question:
Write a command that shows all unique strings. A string consists of one or more words joined by an underscore, a word being one or more alphabetic characters: `lamp change`, `rise reason`, `mei`, but not `15 mei` or `2015 risetime`.

the csv file I already stripped down so it looks like this(1column):

```
lamp_change_10_augustus_2015_16_15_28_637
```

I need only the "lamp_change" part of this string/column.

running on macOS terminal. I already tried to use a grep command, but it only shows all the `lamp_change` for example instead of just one. I think I need to use regular expressions combined with the `grep` command

the csv file looks like this:

```
amp_change_06_augustus_2015_12_19_30_785
lamp_change_06_augustus_2015_12_19_30_989
lamp_change_06_augustus_2015_12_19_31_007
lamp_change_10_augustus_2015_16_15_27_451
lamp_change_10_augustus_2015_16_15_28_479
lamp_change_10_augustus_2015_16_15_28_637
lamp_change_10_augustus_2015_16_15_28_644
morning_backup_hour
morning_backup_minute
start_experiment
target_url
0009_02_juni_2015_adherence_importance
```

this is what i tried

```
$ grep -E  "([a-z]+_[a-z]+)" hue_string.csv|sort|uniq
```

this gave me the same answer

```
$ sed -E 's/ \+/\n/' hue_string.csv
```

the result of this code is just the same as the csv file. It should contain all the actions like `lamp_change`, `bedtime_tonight`, etc in a list.

Comment: Please clarify whether "*augustus*", "*juni*", and "*morning_backup_minute*" should be in the sorted output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-o` (or `--only-matching`) switch:

```
grep -ioE  "([a-z]+_[a-z]+)" hue_string.csv | sort -u
```

Output:

```
adherence_importance
amp_change
lamp_change
morning_backup
start_experiment
target_url
```

---

Notes:  the `-i` switch makes the search case-insensitive.  `sort -u` is simpler than `sort | uniq`.  The answer above assumes the output should be two words with a `_` in the middle -- this is what the *OP* code finds, but the title implies something more inclusive... in which case:

```
grep -ioE  "([a-z][a-z_]+[a-z])" foo|sort -u
```

Outputs:

```
adherence_importance
amp_change
augustus
juni
lamp_change
morning_backup_hour
morning_backup_minute
start_experiment
target_url
```